# Spring-MVC 3 to SpringMVC 5 Migration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am migrating Spring-MVC application from version 3.2 to 5.0. I have gone through the Spring document and updated the required tags. While compiling I am getting few issues from the `spring-security.xml` file. I am using Tomcat version 9 and Spring version 5.0.4. Attached `spring-security.xml` and error log. Please help.

**spring-security.xml**

```xml
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<http pattern="/resource/**" security="none" />
<http entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" use-expressions="true"> 
<intercept-url pattern="/web/**" access="permitAll" />
<intercept-url pattern="/j_spring security_check" access="isAnonymous()" /> 
<intercept-url pattern="/web/j_spring security_check" access="isAnonymous()" /> <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('USER_ADMINISTRATION', 'IT_SUPPORT')" />
<logout success-handler-ref="CustomLogoutHandler" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
<access-denied-handler error-page="/web/Default.html" /> 

<custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" /> 
<custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myAuthFilter"/> 
<custom-filter position="LAST" ref="appFilter" />
<session-management session-authentication strategy-ref="sas" invalid-session-url="/web/Auth.html" /> 
</http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"> 
    <authentication-provider ref="CustomAuthenticationProvider"/>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy"/>
    <beans:bean id="CustomLogoutHandler" class="com.test.authentication.CustomLogoutHandler"/>
    <beans:bean id="CustomAuthentication Provider" class="com.test.authentication.CustomAuthenticationProvider"/>
    <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.test.authentication.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/> 
    <beans:bean id="appFilter" class="com.test.asg.filter.ApplicationFilter"/>
    <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationFailureHandler" class="com.test.authentication.CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler"/>


    <beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" /> 
    <beans:property name="sessionexpiredUrl" value="/web/Default.html" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="myAuthFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas" /> 
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authentication Manager" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="customAuthenticationFailureHandler"/> 
    <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
    <beans:property name="usernameParameter" value="username"/>
    <beans:property name="passwordParameter" value="password"/>
    </beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
<beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:list>
        
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry"/>
        <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" /> 
        <beans:property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="false" />
        </beans:bean> 
        
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy"> 
        </beans:bean>
        
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry"/>
        </beans:beans>
    </beans:list>
</beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:beans>

    <beans:bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />

    <beans:bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"> 
    <beans:constructor-arg name="loginFormUrl" value="/web/Default.html" />
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

**error details**

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener] 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 
org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1' while setting bean property 'sourceList with key [1]; nested exception is
'org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1': Cannot resolve 
reference to bean 'concurrencyFilter' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name concurrencyFilter defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'sessionexpiredUrl' of bean class [org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter]: 
Bean property 'sessionexpiredUrl' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver resolveReference (BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary (BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:401)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:159)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1613)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1357) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) 
at org. .springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultlistableBeanFactory.java:741) 
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) 
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291) 
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4716)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5177) 
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) 
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:999) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal (StandardHost.java:843) 
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) 
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.Standard Service.startInternal(StandardService.java:434) 
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) 
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) 
at org.apache.catalina.startup. Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
at org.apache.catalina.startup. Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
```

Comment: As indicated in the migration guide(https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-deprecations-web-csf), the `sessionexpiredUrl` has also been moved to the `ConcurrentSessionFilter` constructor. Please also note that Spring Security 5.0.4 has reached its end-of-life meaning no further maintenance releases or security patches planned. Please migrate to a supported version (5.2.x, 5.3.x, 5.4.x or 5.5.x) as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will update